# How best to write a query that will read less data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is one table Crosses

| ArticleId | CrossArticleId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 5 | 10 |
| 5 | 12 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 6 | 10 |
| 6 | 13 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 8 | 10 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 9 | 13 |
| 9 | 15 |

First, we get all the rows that have ArticleId = 1 and get the following rows into the temporary table @tempFlatCrosses

| ArticleId | CrossArticleId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 9 |

Next you need to select

```
select с.CrossArticleId from Crosses c
inner join @tempFlatCrosses f on c.ArticleId = f.CrossArticleId
```

then we will get a lot of duplicates, it will read a lot of extra rows from the Crosses table.

```
10
12
10
13
10
13
15
```

I understand that you can get by with the Distinct operator, but I still wanted the query to scan less data from the table. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Use an `EXISTS` instead?

Comment: Yes, I used it. I just don’t know how to tell the server that there is already such a record with ArticleId

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `EXISTS` will short circuit as soon as it finds a row. Of course, if you have appropriate indexes, the data engine will be able to seek to those rows as well, rather than scan.

Comment: Why the temporary table?

Comment: @jarlh this is just an example

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: In your comments you have turned the question into a performance question. Performance questions require the full table definition,  index definitions and the execution plan (using Paste The Plan)

Comment: @DaleK This is not a matter of the plan request. The point is in the query selection algorithm. BenderBoy Answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BenderBoy answered. Thanks!

> so make an additional lookup table where you cache the Ids by whatever logic you’re interested in. gain faster querying in exchange for slower inserts/updates

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for a temporary table, you can use a self-join in this scenario :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.CrossArticleId
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2 on t1.CrossArticleId = t2.ArticleId
WHERE t1.ArticleId = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fXXpKsr3)

Comment: Thank. I know this solution. When I have more 1000 records from `inner join mytable`, server can reed more 100 000 record. Finaly  I have 2000 records after disctinct
Probably my question is stupid, there are no other ideas

Comment: To speed up the query, maybe you need to add some indexes if not yet added, try this index `CREATE INDEX INDEX1 ON mytable (ArticleId, CrossArticleId);`

Comment: I wanted to reduce the number of logical reads. And the table has the necessary indexes)

Comment: @ArturMakvetsyan so make an additional lookup table where you cache the Ids by whatever logic you’re interested in. gain faster querying in exchange for slower inserts/updates

Comment: @BenderBoy but I have more 100 million records in the table Crosses

Comment: @ArturMakvetsyan dealing with lots of data is exactly what caches are for. you wouldn’t add that complexity for 1000 records.

Comment: @BenderBoy I understand the idea, I need to think... If you cache it, there will be x100 lines in the cache. In any case, thanks, I'll think about it.